# findstr: How to escape the dot?

Tags: command-line, cmd.exe

I don't understand why `findstr` doesn't work as I want.

I have the following files in my test directory:

```
aaa.jpg
bbb.png
ccc.svg

aaa_s.jpg
bbb_s.png
ccc_s.svg

aaa_small.jpg
bbb_small.png
ccc_small.svg
```

And I have the following line to pass directly to cmd.exe:

```
for /f "delims=" %f in ('dir /b /a:-d ^| findstr /ile "gif jpg png svg" ^| findstr /ie "_s.*"') do echo "%f"
```

To my opinion, it should match the following files:

```
aaa_s.jpg
bbb_s.png
ccc_s.svg
```

However, it's actually matches

```
aaa_s.jpg
bbb_s.png
ccc_s.svg

aaa_small.jpg
bbb_small.png
ccc_small.svg
```

Yes, I understand that the problem is that the dot works as "any character" instead of being treated literally.

```
findstr /ie "_s.*"
```

Bot how can I escape it? Using backslash, i.e. changing it to

```
findstr /ie "_s\.*"
```

doesn't work.

Comment: The `.` is in fact escaped with `\ `, according to this post https://serverfault.com/questions/123483/doing-logical-or-comparisons-with-findstr-exe. Is there something else wrong with your script? Btw nobody understands how `findstr` works :) It seems that David already answered, so there you go

Comment: "Btw nobody understands how findstr works" - Haha. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### How can I escape the wildcard `.` in order to match a literal `.` character?

You are on the right lines with using a `\`, however you need an additional `.` in order to find the remaining characters.

```
findstr /ie "_s\..*"
```

Example (type and a `cmd` shell):

```
F:\test>dir /b /a:-d | findstr /ile "gif jpg png svg" | findstr /ie "_s.*"
aaa_s.jpg
bbb_s.jpg
ccc_s.jpg
aaa_small.jpg
bbb_small.jpg
ccc_small.jpg

F:\test>dir /b /a:-d | findstr /ile "gif jpg png svg" | findstr /ie "_s\..*"
aaa_s.jpg
bbb_s.jpg
ccc_s.jpg
```

So your batch file should contain:

```
for /f "delims=" %f in ('dir /b /a:-d ^| findstr /ile "gif jpg png svg" ^| findstr /ie "_s\..*"') do echo "%f"
```

Comment: Agreed. The REGEXP `.*` says 1 or more characters. The REGEXP `\..*` says a dot, plus one or more characters.

Answer (score 3):

For this specific task you can also escape the **`"."`** in the **`findstr`** by not using it if you replace:

**`dir /b /a:-d`**     →    **`where .:*_s.*`**

**`findstr /ie "_s\.*"`**     →    **`findstr /ei  "gif  jpg  png  svg"`**

```all-bat
where .:*_s.*|findstr /ei  "gif  jpg  png  svg"

for /f delims^= %f in ('where .:*_s.*^|findstr /ei  "gif  jpg  png  svg"')do echo "%~nxf"
```